# Module to support message archive in ejabberd v13.12

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, jabberd2, mod-archive-odbc

I know that mod_archive (mod_archive_odbc) is there to support message archive[XEP-0313]
But it does not work with ejabberd v13.12. 
**Is some one found it (mod_archive) working  with v13.12 then please guide me how I could do that ?**

I just wanted to know if mod_archive could not work with v13.12 then is there any other module I could use, I have not considered any implementation of XEP-0313 for ejabberd.
Is any one using XEP-0313 implementation in production ? Please let me know

Please share what ever you think could help here.

FYI I will use mysql as storage for chat messages. If any one have found any drawbacks using mysql as a backend for ejabberd please report, that would be a great help too.

Thanks

Comment: I just configured ejabberd 14.07 with mysql.Which module should be adopted for message archiving?Is it okay if I go with mod_archive2?

Comment: I am not sure if any of them work, In my opinion none of them would work for message archiving in ejabberd version > 13

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd's mod_archive implements old XEP-0136, which was too complex to implement and was not widely adopted. New XEP-0313 is a different message archiving protocol, you can try [Prosody](http://prosody.im/) XMPP server and their implementation - [mod_mam](https://code.google.com/p/prosody-modules/wiki/mod_mam).

Comment: Thanks vitalyster, I know that, But ejabberd is what I want to go with.